# How can I add a trait to a case class?

Tags: scala, traits

I have a domain model that looks like this:

```
case class Account(id: Int, name: String)

trait BalanceTotal {
  def balance: BigDecimal
}
```

My goal is to have a simple, lightweight `Account` case class and then an enhanced class `Account with BalanceTotal` that will only be created inside a method that does the balance calculation (which is expensive).

With this structure, I can statically ensure that I'm never counting on a balance being present when I just have a lightweight object. I know about `Option`, of course, but I want the type-checker to prevent code from using the lightweight object where I need the balance-enriched object, and vice-versa, and I don't think `Option` gives me that.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is:

```
for{ Account(id,name) <- accounts } {
  yield Account(id, name) with BalanceTotal {
    override val balance = BigDecimal(44)
  }
}
```

but that fails with:

```
';' expected but 'with' found
```

If I try to use `new Account` instead of `Account`, I get:

```
super constructor arguments cannot reference unconstructed `this`
```

which I assume has something to do with the voodoo that makes case classes work.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

*Update*: On further consideration, I guess this has something to do with the prohibition against case class inheritance. But I really do need case class magic here: I'm relying on the generated `apply` and `unapply` methods for my ScalaQuery mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works OK for me:

```
>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.
7.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Account(id: Int, name: String)

trait BalanceTotal {
  def balance: BigDecimal
}
val enrichedAccount = new Account(1, "foo") with BalanceTotal {
  override val balance = BigDecimal(44)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Account
defined trait BalanceTotal
enrichedAccount: Account with BalanceTotal = Account(1,foo)
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right. It looks like the problem is that my actual code looks like `for{Account(id, name, foo) <- accounts} { yield new Account(id, name, foo) { ... } }`  It's the usage of closed-over variables that causes the problem.

Comment: @Bill Your new example is wrong because you've put the `yield` keyword inside braces (as well as missing out `new`). It has to come directly after the `for {...}`. Fix that and it works.

Comment: Your example works, but my complete code snippet doesn't. I wonder if it's something to do with ScalaQuery

Comment: Ah ha! The constructor had been declared private, so my for loop wasn't able to invoke the constructor: the error message was just confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work because of the missing `new`. `Account(id, name)` actually calls `Account.apply(id, name)` and that returns an `Account` on which you cant call `with`. `new Account(id, name) with BalanceTotal` gets translated to an anonymous class that extends `Account` with `BalanceTotal`. Hope that helps to understand why your code does not work.

Comment: Read further down: I tried with `new Account(...)` and got a different error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the for but the yield. Use brackets as the following and it will work:

```
for ( Acount(id, name) <- accounts) yield 
  (new Account(id, name) with BalanceTotal { 
    override val balance = BigDecimal(42) 
  })
```